# I want to pay employees based on a percentage of each job they finish.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to pay my employees a set amount, based on a percentage of the job. I need an equation for it that accounts for overtime. For example, Bob worked 45 hours and I want to pay him $3,000. How do I figure his regular hourly wage?

Comment: I can help you with a formula, but your narrative is confusing.  It sounds like you want a formula to apply at the end of two weeks.  Please give the inputs, and desired outputs, for just that two week period.

Comment: OK, let me try again. Because the overtime is calculated per week, I really only need a formula that covers one week for simplicity. Person A worked 48 hours and I want to pay him $2,500. What was his hourly wage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding your question, but if Bob worked $45$ hours in one week and you want to pay him $\$3,000$ for that week's worth of work, you could do the following: $$\frac{\$3,000}{45\text{ hours}}\times\frac{1/45}{1/45}=\frac{\$66.67}{1\text{ hour}}=\$66.67\text{ per hour}$$

For the other example you mentioned in a comment, we can use the same formula of ${\text{total pay}\over\text{hours worked}}:$ $$\frac{\$2,500}{48\text{ hours}}\times\frac{1/48}{1/48}=\frac{\$52.08}{1\text{ hour}}=\$52.08\text{ per hour}$$

Comment: I need the equation to take into account over time, which is 1.5 times the regular pay for everything over 40 hours. I just need to work backwards, where I know the total amount I want to pay first. For example: I want to pay Bob $1,445 for a 45 hour work week. How do I get to the point where I know that his hourly rate was $30/ hour with 5 hours at $45/ hour?

Comment: My apologies; this sounds more like what you're looking for:

$$T=\begin{cases}hr, & \text{if $h\le40$} \\ 40r+(h-40)(1.5r), & \text{if $h\gt40$}\end{cases}$$

$T$ is the total amount paid, $h$ is the total number of hours worked, and $r$ is the non-overtime hourly rate. If you know $T$ and $h$, you can plug them into the appropriate equation based on the value of $h$ and then solve for $r$. Here are the same equations, but solved for $r$, which might make them easier to work with: $$r=\begin{cases}\dfrac{T}{h}, & \text{if $h\le40$} \\ \dfrac{T}{1.5h-20}, & \text{if $h\gt40$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Also, feel free to upvote and/or accept (the little checkmark underneath the arrows next to my original answer) my answer if any of this was helpful!

Comment: WOWWWWW! You did it! I have struggled with trying to figure this out for years and just like that, poof! You solved it for me! I should have found this web site long long ago, you just made my life so much easier, thank you so much! I upvoted and checked the check too. All the best!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help!